# Check if array contains a specific enum type

Tags: ios, swift, enums

What is the best way to determine if an array of enum types contains a specific enum type, the kicker is the enum cases have associated types

for example, with the following data structure, how would I get the first video

```
let sections = [OnDemandSectionViewModel]

public struct OnDemandSectionViewModel: AutoEquatable {
    public let sectionStyle: SectionHeaderStyle
    public let sectionItems: [OnDemandItemType]
    public let sectionType: SectionType
}

public enum OnDemandItemType: AutoEquatable {
    case video(VideoViewModel)
    case button(ButtonViewModel)
    case game(GameViewModel)
    case collectionGroup(CollectionGroupViewModel)
    case clip(ClipViewModel)
}
```

I'm trying to find the first video, currently, I'm doing the following, but was curious if there is a better way

```
for section in sections {
    for item in section.sectionItems {
        switch item {
        case .video(let video):
            print("This is the first video \(video)")
            return
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even you can use [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1407477-contains) array property. It is far much better than this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `Sequence.first(where:)`, which is pretty much like `contains(where:)`, but instead of simply returning a bool, it returns the first element satisfying the condition in the closure or `nil` if there's no such element.

```
let firstVideo = sections.sectionItems.first(where: { item in
    if case .video = item {
        return true
    }
    return false
})
```

Comment: This has the advantage of working nice with associated values.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need `VideoViewModel` contained in enum it's enough to type

```
if section.sectionItems.contains(where: { item in 
    if case .video = item {
        return true
    }

    return false
}) {
    // Your section contains video
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using filter function example:

```
return section.filter({ $0.sectionType == .video }).first != nil
```

Or

```
return section.filter( { $0.sectionType == .video }).count ?? 0 > 0
```